# Hugo import styles to ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sass, hugo

I have this ASP.NET MVC (C#) site that used to have `gulp`, now they want to move to [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) but I don't know how to "import" the styles from one place to the other.

```
--Solution
  --Hugo Project
    --Styles (I want to get the styles from here)
      --myStyles.scss
  --MVC Project
    --Styles (And "import" them to here in order to be able to reference them)
      --myStyles.scss
```

With `gulp` I used to do it like this:

```
gulp.task('1-build-css', function () {
return gulp.src('./gulp-project/styles/myStyles.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(rename('myStyles.css'))
    .pipe(header(banner, { time: dateformat(new Date(), 'm.d.yyyy H:MM:ss') }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../mvc-project/Styles'))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(rename('myStyles.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../mvc-project/Styles'));
});
```

Is there a way to do this with the tools from Hugo? Perhaps with some command from its CLI or something like that